# Why are some images blurry and others crisp on the same canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas, image-rendering

In a canvas project I am working on, I have a tile based gird, along with a panel of options. I have gotten everything to work, and all the images are crisp, screen resizing is accounted for, there is no anti-aliasing, etc. Everything (graphics wise) is perfect, the problem is that sometimes I need to change the number of rows and columns, and this changes the overall dimensions of the canvas. Due to some other problems, I use a `buffer` canvas inside of the `editor` class, which gets rendered onto the main canvas.

Here is my editor code (only the graphics):

```
export class Editor{
    constructor(spritesheet, toolImages){
        this.spritesheet = spritesheet;
        this.toolImages = toolImages;

        this.rows = 25;
        this.cols = 25;
        this.size = 16;

        this.extra = this.size *3;//extra on the bottom

        this.w = this.cols * this.size;
        this.h = this.rows * this.size + this.extra;


        this.buffer = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d', { alpha:false, desynchronized:true });
        this.buffer.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        this.buffer.canvas.width = this.cols * this.size;
        this.buffer.canvas.height = this.rows * this.size + this.extra;
        this.buffer.canvas.style.imageRendering =  'pixelated'
        this.buffer.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

        this.map = [];//2d map object, not important
        
    }
    addRow(){
        this.rows++;
        this.h = this.rows * this.size + this.extra;
        this.map[this.rows-1] = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++){
            this.map[this.rows-1][i] = 'blank';
        }
        this.buffer.canvas.height = this.rows * this.size + this.extra;
        console.log('adding: ' + this.rows);
    };
    delRow(){
        this.rows--;
        this.h = this.rows * this.size + this.extra;
        this.buffer.canvas.height = this.rows * this.size + this.extra;

        delete this.map[this.rows];
        console.log('deleting: ' + this.rows);
    };

    drawToBuffer(cutx, cuty, pasteX, pasteY, mult = 1){
        this.buffer.drawImage(this.spritesheet, cutx, cuty, this.size, this.size, pasteX, pasteY, this.size * mult, this.size * mult);
        
    }
    prepare(){
        this.buffer.clearRect(0,0,this.buffer.canvas.width,this.buffer.canvas.height);
        this.buffer.fillStyle = '#00131B';
        this.buffer.fillRect(0,0,this.buffer.canvas.width,this.buffer.canvas.height);
        this.buffer.fillStyle = '#000000';
        this.buffer.fillRect(0, this.buffer.canvas.height - this.extra + 1, this.buffer.canvas.width, this.size-2);

        let amount = Math.floor(this.buffer.canvas.width/6);

        let Y = this.size * (this.rows +1);
        let S;
        this.buffer.fillStyle = '#555555';
        switch(this.editorShow){
        //there are more tabs, but they all look like this one:

            case 'walls':
                S = (this.w - this.size*2)/4;
                this.drawToBuffer(0, 25*this.size,  0, Y, 2);
                this.drawToBuffer(0, 27*this.size,  S, Y, 2);
                this.drawToBuffer(0, 28*this.size,S*2, Y, 2);
                this.drawToBuffer(0, 29*this.size,S*3, Y, 2);
                this.drawToBuffer(0, 30*this.size,S*4, Y, 2);
            break;
        }
//toolbar images
        this.buffer.drawImage(this.toolImages[0], 3, this.buffer.canvas.height - this.extra);
        this.buffer.drawImage(this.toolImages[1], amount+3, this.buffer.canvas.height - this.extra);
        this.buffer.drawImage(this.toolImages[2], amount*2+3, this.buffer.canvas.height - this.extra);
        this.buffer.drawImage(this.toolImages[3], amount*3+3, this.buffer.canvas.height - this.extra);
        this.buffer.drawImage(this.toolImages[4], amount*4+3, this.buffer.canvas.height - this.extra);
        this.buffer.drawImage(this.toolImages[5], amount*5+3, this.buffer.canvas.height - this.extra);

    }
    render(context){
        context.drawImage(this.buffer.canvas,0,0);
    }

}
```

And here is the main code (that is running in the browser):

```
const context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');


window.setInterval(()=>{
   context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
   context.canvas.style.imageRendering = 'pixelated';
   context.canvas.width = currentEditor.w;
   context.canvas.height = currentEditor.h;
   currentEditor.prepare();
   currentEditor.render(context);
   resizeLevel(currentEditor.w, currentEditor.h);
}, 1000/60);

//the resize function
function resizeLevel(w,h) {

    // Get the height and width of the window
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    let width_height_ratio = w / h;
    // This makes sure the DISPLAY canvas is resized in a way that maintains the MAP's width / height ratio.
    if (width / height < width_height_ratio) height = Math.floor(width  / width_height_ratio);
    else                                         width  = Math.floor(height * width_height_ratio);

    // This sets the CSS of the DISPLAY canvas to resize it to the scaled height and width.
    context.canvas.style.height = height + 'px';
    context.canvas.style.width  = width  + 'px';
    //this centers the canvas
    context.canvas.style.marginTop = (innerHeight/2 - height/2) + 'px';
    context.canvas.style.marginLeft = (innerWidth/2 - width/2) + 'px';
   
}
```

All of the images are crisp to begin with, but whenever I add or subtract rows or columns, all of the images that are scaled by 2 (`this.drawToBuffer(w, x , y, z, 2)`) become blurry, even if I add a row and delete a row.

Before:
[image: Crisp image]

After:
[image: Blurry image]

I want the images to be like the first one, crisp and pixelated, and no matter what I try, the images that are scaled up will not look crisp, I have made sure that they are all on integers, set the image rendering of the buffer to `pixelated`, and turned off `imageSmothingEnabled`.

Here is the full site: http://labyrinth-sweeper.herokuapp.com/

And here is the full code: https://github.com/Hello-World25/Amaze-V2

How can I get these scaled images to look crisp?

Comment: I'm sure it's to do with sub-sampling and anti-aliasing. I don't envy you.

Comment: Yea, it most likely does, but I think I've set everything up right. Key word: think, probably missed something obvious, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809345/html5-canvas-is-there-a-way-to-resize-image-with-nearest-neighbour-resampling (I searched "canvas resampling")

Comment: Thanks, Ill look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever canvas is resized, it's context gets reset, which means that `imageSmoothingEnabled` goes back to default value `true`. Make sure to set it back to `false` after resize and before next `drawImage` call.

Comment: Sweet, that fixed it. This stuff is really annoying, I actually found out that that fixed it earlier, but I also did a bunch of other stuff, so I wasn't sure what had caused it to work. Ill keep this in mind next time though